# PhoneGap and Windows Phone - no plugin works

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build

I'm currently experiencing the frustrating problem that in a PhoneGap app for Windows Phone no plugin works. For example, when I am testing like the following:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan()
```

the console says `TypeError: Unable to get property 'barcodeScanner' of undefined or null reference`
Plugins are in config.xml like

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
```

It works perfectly on Android.
I'm using PhoneGap Build as build service. Any ideas?

Comment: that version is not the latest, try this one `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" version="0.2.13" />` additionally you can try not specifying the version number so that is builds with the latest version allways `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />`

Comment: I updated the question and used another example cause the version is not the reason.

Comment: Are there any other errors or warnings in the console? My hunch is that there is some JS that is erring on the WP8 webview that is stopping all other JS from working.

Comment: Removed all other js for testing - nothing. It's only the plugin call that won't work on WP8

Comment: are you waiting for `deviceready` event to fire before calling to plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is current a PhoneGap build service issue. WP builds are delivered without plugins. Hope this error will be fixed soon.